# SSIS flat file export timestamps have excess precision?

Tags: ssis

SQL 2008 R2, have a simple export to a Flat File Destination. Timestamp columns are set to DT_DBTIMESTAMP in the destination, which according to the docs "The fractional seconds have a maximum scale of 3 digits." However, my exported files have 7 digits of fractional second precision, as defined by DT_DBTIMESTAMP2 in the docs. The columns of course cannot be reimported into SQL Server, because of the excess fractional second positions.

Does anyone know why SSIS exports datetime columns with a different definition than the SSIS data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the destination datatypes and make sure they are DB_TIMESTAMP not DB_TIMESTAMP2. 
Right-click on destination component and choose "Show Advanced Editor...", then check data types on "Input and Output Properties" tab.